# Run unit test cases in order from Azure

Tags: azure, selenium-webdriver, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I want to run C# Selenium automated test cases from Azure in same order in which they are in test suite with order number.

Like:

Title
Test4
Test2
Test1
Test3
So they will execute in order like Test4, Test2, Test1, Test3

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Pipelines as part of Azure Devops to run selenium tests

See here for an example lab
https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/selenium/

Comment: I want to run test cases in order, as when we trigger those from Dev Azure test cases will be picked for execution in random order. Not in the order I want to execute them. Is there any way or settings with which we can trigger automated test cases in particular order not in random order.